# nunit-console won't run any tests

Tags: c#, mono, nunit

I'm test-driving the .Net ecosystem via Mono, but I've run into a problem with NUnit. I have the following example test file:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void FailingTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail("A message");
        }

        [Test]
        public void PassingTest()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Which I'm building and running via:

```
cweber@mbp ~/temp/monoexample$ dmcs tests.cs -target:library -r:$NUNIT_FRAMEWORK_DLL
cweber@mbp ~/temp/monoexample$ ls tests.dll
tests.dll
cweber@mbp ~/temp/monoexample$ nunit-console tests.dll
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Unix 14.5.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( 4.2.1 (explicit/6dd2d0d Fri Nov  6 12:25:19 EST 2015) )

.N.N
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 2, Time: 0.014 seconds
```

As you can see, neither of the tests are running.

I've Googled everything I can think of, and I've done all of the experimenting I can think of (e.g., removing the namespace, messing with `fixture` and `run` flags, etc). I've clearly simplified this example as much as I know how, but I've run out of ideas. Please let me know if I can provide any more information!

I'm sorry to ask this question if the answer ends up being obvious.

Comment: Your test class must be public. Enjoy ;)

Comment: @felix-b I figured it would be something trivial/silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in your `TestResult.xml` file and you will see the reason way, class is not public ;-)

```
    <results>
      <test-case name="Tests.Tests.FailingTest" executed="False">
        <reason>
          <message><![CDATA[Fixture class is not public]]></message>
        </reason>
      </test-case>
      <test-case name="Tests.Tests.PassingTest" executed="False">
        <reason>
          <message><![CDATA[Fixture class is not public]]></message>
        </reason>
      </test-case>
    </results>
```

Comment: I have no XML file, but it's good to know that some useful debug info goes in there! I'll make sure to generate one if/when I have problems in the future! :)

Comment: the `TestResult.xml` should be generated by default in 2.4.8... you can also redirect the output to the console via `-xmlConsole`, but either way, the reason/message section will usually show you the details of any issues... ;-) Have fun

Comment: Strange. I'm not seeing it. There is an xml flag though; presumably I could force it. I'll play around.

Comment: You can have a overview of the Xml with [ReportUnit](http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/)